# Combining two fields into one hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, ms-access-2007

So I have two columns in my database, "URL" and "Title".

The first one contains bare URL in the form of http://something.somewhere.com, the second is the descriptive name of it (quite intuitive).

I need to write a query which would combine these two columns into one "URL" like that [A descriptive name](http://something.somewhere.com).

I've tried with the # symbol this way:

```
descriptive_name#url#
```

and it works if you input it manually, but apparently it doesn't work with queries.
I've tried:

```
UPDATE table SET table.[URL] = (SELECT [Title] & "#" & [URL] & "#" FROM table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` query syntax is wrong.

It should be:

```
UPDATE table SET table.[URL] = [Title] & "#" & [URL] & "#"
```

Comment: Thanks! I overcomplicated it.